# Does Verlinde's entropic gravity relate Hawing radiation to bodies other than black holes?

Tags: gravity, entropy, quantum-gravity

To the best of my understanding this is the essence of the point he's trying to establish, am I right in thinking this?

Comment: All bodies that are not in thermal equilibrium radiate thermal radiation. Hawking radiation is the thermal radiation of a black hole by definition. But yeah, Verlinde's idea was to associate a system with an Unruh-like temperature and then combine the holographic principle with some fundamental thermodynamics along with one additional speculation on how the entropy shifts to suggest the entropic nature of gravity, although this description was disproved or, at least, not all of his postulations can be correct.

Comment: @PanosC. Cool, cheers!